# Factorial formula problem

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, factorial

Prove that  $(n-r)!(r!)$ divides $ n! $ i know its a factorial formula and it might be easy but i stuck .I tried induction to $n$ or analyzing the factorials but im missing something

Comment: did you tried induction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combinatorial argument. How many groups of size $k$ can be formed from $k$ students? There are $n$ options for the first student, $n-1$ options for the second $\dots (n-k+1)$ options for the $k$'th student. Therefore there are $n\cdot (n-1)\cdot\dots (n-k+1)=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ possible groups.

However we have overcounted! Because in a group of students there is no such thing as a first student or a second student. Every group of student has been counted exactly $k!$ times since this is the number of ways to order the $k$ students of a given group. Therefore the number of groups is $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$. Clearly the number of groups is an integer number. Then $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ is an integer and so $k!(n-k)!$ divides $n!$

Comment: I don't see why the number of groups must be an integer. Why can't you cut a student in half?

Comment: Cutting a student in half yields at most one student if you are very lucky. In most cases the result is zero students

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution via group theory. Consider the group $S_n$, it has $n!$ elements. Now consider the subgroup of $S_n$ consisting of the permutations such that elements in $\{1,2,3\dots k\}$ always go to elements of $\{1,2,3\dots k\}$, it has order $k!(n-k)!$ so by lagrange's theorem $k!(n-k)!$ divides $n!$

Comment: why is that the number of the order of the subgroup?

Comment: There are $k!$ ways to permute the elements of $\{1,2,3,4\dots k\}$ and there are $n-k$ ways to permute the elements of $\{k+1,k+2\dots n\}$